# How can I combine two hashes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, hashmap

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/197/

```
a = {
    'a' : 'one'
}

o = {
    'a' : '1',
    'b' : '2',
    'd' : '3'
}

z = $.merge(a, o);

console.log( z ); // expected { 'a' : 'one',  'b' : '2', 'd' : '3' }
```

I don't want to concatonate or join two hashs, I want to merge them into one hash, as you can do with Ruby's merge method. So as I say, I want to create the hash:

```
{ 'a' : 'one',  'b' : '2', 'd' : '3' }
```

From `a` and `o`

Comment: These are not arrays, but objects.

Comment: So you say what you expected, but not what you got?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) as `a` and `b` are objects not arrays

```
a = {
    'a': 'one'
}

o = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'd': '3'
}

z = $.extend({}, o, a);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZBuj9/)

Note: need to look at the first params being an empty object and the order of params passed

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing serverside stuff for ages and completely forgotten jquery it seems!

Comment: Or append `a` to `o` like this: `$.extend(o, a);`